# How to set a ninja hello world project?

Tags: ninja

I want to test the ninja build system but i really can't figure where should i start from. Could you provide please a step-by-step tutorial on how to set a "hello world" project? I guess this thing would be helpfull for a lot of people.

Comment: using what buildsystem generator?